# projecting functional dependencies onto another relation

Tags: functional-dependencies

consider the relation `R(ABCDE)` with the following FD's:

- AB -> C
- BC -> D
- CD -> E
- DE -> A
- AE -> B

Project these FD's onto the relation of `S(ABCD)`. Which of the following FD's hold in the projected relation?

1. A -> B
2. A -> D
3. BC -> A
4. AC -> B

*the wording in the above question is directly copied from an assignment*

The correct answer is given to be 3.

since the last 3 FD's contain E they do not hold in the projection onto R(ABCD) I believe. So that leaves me with
`AB -> C` and `BC -> D` I can not figure out how to determine the correct answer from my current though process.

Comment: @philipxy the exact wording is : "Project these FD's onto the relation S(A,B,C,D). Which of the following FD's holds in the projected relation?"

Comment: It's unfortunate that your assignment says that. It is sloppy writing. Still, that's no reason for you to use it. Why do *you* think it means anything? Please edit your question to say you are quoting your assignment. If you have actually been given a definition of what those words mean used that way, please let me know. Otherwise, please edit your question to say what you think that means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is not clear. I am assuming that you are asking which of the last four dependencies hold in the relation R(ABCD): the answer is the third. This can be simply proved by computing the closure of `BC` in the original set of dependencies:

```
BC+ = BC
BC+ = BCD    (using BC → D)
BC+ = BCDE   (using CD → E)
BC+ = BCDEA  (using DE → A)
```

so, BC is a candidate key and determines A, so that `BC → A`holds also in `R(ABCD)`. If you try to compute the closure for all the other left hand sides of the four dependencies, you will never find the right side, so they do not hold in `R(ABCD)`.

Why the answer can be obtained by computing the closure of the determinant?

Let's call `FS` the projection of the original set of dependencies `F` over the relation `S(ABCD)`. So, for the definition of the projection of a set of dependencies, we have that:

FS = { X → Y ∈ F<sup>+</sup> | X,Y ⊆ ABCD }

and the question asks if certain dependencies belong to FS. But since the computation of FS requires the computation of F<sup>+</sup>, which is an exponential task, instead of calculating it, we check, for each of the four dependencies X → Y, if it belongs to F<sup>+</sup>. This is equivalent to the polynomial task of calculating the closure of X and finding if Y belong to it or not (we already know that the dependencies have all the attributes in the set ABCD).

So the answer is to calculate the closure of all the left hand parts of the dependencies and see if the right part is contained in it or not. And this is true only for the third dependency.

Comment: I think I cleared up the question in my post but yes you are right in your assumption. My thought process was to compute the closure of both BC and AC since the other 2 FD's wouldn't hold since they have the E term in them. Can you explain why I have to compute these closures?

Answer (score 1):

"Project these FD's onto the relation S(A,B,C,D)" is sloppy writing. (Although you comment that you are quoting your assignment.) Presumably this is trying to say, if these FDs hold in R(ABCDE) then which of the following FDs holds in its projection on ABCD.

When some FDs hold, other ones must also hold because those ones do. Thus many more FDs hold in R than the ones you were given. Moreover some of the FDs that hold but aren't given hold because some of the FDs using E hold--even though they themselves do not contain E. So first you need to find more of the FDs in R, until you find one that will be kept after projecting since they don't involve E.

One way is to find F+ (the closure of the set of FDs). But it can be very large. What we can do instead is use the notion of a closure of an attribute set. That is the set of all attributes determined by an attribute set. (From the determined attributes we know all the FDs that hold with that determinant.) There is an algorithm for finding it. If an answer FD determinant is a determinant in F then we can calculate its closure in R to see if its answer FD also holds in R.

If none of the determinants of the FDs appeared as determinants in F then we would have to start generating FDs in F+ until we got one with a determinant that was also a determinant among the answers. Then we could apply the previous step.